# Updating a custom post status after an expiry date rather than trashing it

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, wp-update-post, draft

I have set up a custom post type of featured products. Within that post type I have a custom date field for an expiry date. Currently when the date expires, the post gets moved to the Trash. I'm looking to change this though and hoped somebody maybe able to help.

My current function is:

```
function _delete_expired_fp() {
  $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'featured_product',
      'posts_per_page' => -1
  );

  $fproducts = new WP_Query($args);
  if ($fproducts->have_posts()):
      while($fproducts->have_posts()): $fproducts->the_post();    

          $expiration_date = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'featured_product_expiration', true );
          $expiration_date_time = strtotime($expiration_date);

          if ($expiration_date_time < time()) {
              wp_trash_post(get_the_ID());
                         
          }

      endwhile;
  endif;
}
```

What I'd like to happen is rather than send the expired post to the trash, I would like to change it's status to Draft. I believe I can use something like `wp_update_post` but I'm not too sure how to implement this into my existing code as I'm sure there is more to it.

Any help much appreciated.

*EDIT

```
wp_update_post( array(
                'ID'            => $post->ID,
                'post_status'   => 'draft',
            ) );
```

Could something like this work?

Comment: You’d also have to make sure your new status wasn’t returned by the query, else you’d keep reapplying the new status, or filter that out done other way. But otherwise wp_update_post should work fine yes.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. So could I use something like the above *EDIT ( I have edited my original post)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I found to update post status based on a date:

[Change a Post's Status based on the date from a custom field? (for Event posts)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/412054/change-a-posts-status-based-on-the-date-from-a-custom-field-for-event-posts)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/260258)

Comment: If this is answered by another question on this site then you could flag this question as a duplicate of that one.