# Change a Post's Status based on the date from a custom field? (for Event posts)

Tags: wp-cron, post-status

I've found many posts on this topic and tried to use their solution, but none has worked so far...

I have an `Event` custom post type with an `event_end_date` custom field. I'm trying to create a PHP snippet to automatically change the status of an Event post from Published to Draft (or whatever) based on the date in `event_end_date`. Basically, the day after the end of the event, I want it to be unpublished and changed to draft.

The code I'm currently using is as follows:

```
wp_schedule_event(time(), 'daily', 'expire_events');
//add_action('init','expire_events');
function expire_events() {
    $the_query = get_posts( 'post_type=event' );    
    foreach($the_query as $single_post) {
        $id=$single_post->ID;
        $event_end_date=get_post_meta($id, '$event_end_date', true );
        if($event_end_date!=''){
            $today=date("Y-m-d");
            if($event_end_date<$today){
                $update_post = array(
                'ID'            => $id,
                'post_status'   =>  'draft',
                'post_type' =>  'event' );
                wp_update_post($update_post);
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

This code has been copied/pasted from somewhere else and I've adapted it with my custom field name and post type, but it doesn't seem to be working...

Any help would more than welcome, as I don't understand PHP enough to know if what I'm pasting really makes sense :/

Thank you!

PS: The date format in the function seems to match the date format from the custom field, in case you're wondering. For context: I'm using GeneratePress / GenerateBlocks and MetaBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several little issues with your code.  This is what I use for the exact same thing though and it works:

```
// expire events on date field.
if (!wp_next_scheduled('expire_events')){
  wp_schedule_event(time(), 'daily', 'expire_events'); // this can be hourly, twicedaily, or daily
}

add_action('expire_events', 'expire_events_function');

function expire_events_function() {
    $today = date('Ymd');
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => array('event'), // post types you want to check
        'posts_per_page' => -1 
    );
    $posts = get_posts($args);
    foreach($posts as $p){
        $expiredate = get_field('event_and_date', $p->ID, false, false); // get the raw date from the db
        if ($expiredate) {
            if($expiredate < $today){
                $postdata = array(
                    'ID' => $p->ID,
                    'post_status' => 'draft'
                );
                wp_update_post($postdata);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Place this code in your functions.php and load the site one time to set your CRON job.  You can text to ensure your CRON is set and run it right away as well with wp-cli or a CRON plugin.

I would suggest next time though to prefix your post types so you know they are your own, for cleaner code, and to reduce potential conflicts.  (ie `event` could be `nom_event`)

EDIT:  Try changing this line:

```
$expiredate = get_field('event_and_date', $p->ID, false, false);
```

To this:

```
$expiredate = get_post_meta($p->ID, 'event_end_date', true );
```

(this line is what your original code should have looked like as well...without the `$` in front of event_end_date)

If this isn't working you can contact me on my site (it's pretty easy to figure out)

Comment: thank you, but it doesn't seem to be working either. Just be sure I went into my custom field settings and forced the same Y-m-d format on the date field saved in the db. I manually triggered the cron but I'm not seeing any update to the posts status. I then went and changed `daily` to `hourly` in case that's causing a problem, and I'll see in an hour if anything changed. Because of that time delay it's not easy to test if the script works.

Comment: In wp cli run this command: `wp cron event run expire_events`.  That will run the event immediately.

Comment: I installed the WP Crontrol plugin instead as I don't have access to CLI easily. I can see the script in the cron events, and I trigged it manually. (see https://i.imgur.com/1P5BSea.png) However, the page I'm expecting to change status to Draft did no change... I have to assume the problem comes from the script?

Comment: In case someone else reads this: I want to clarify that there is a typo in the code rudket posted, the custom field is "event_end_date" instead of "event_and_date". I have made the correction in the script running on my site. So that's not why the script isn't working

Comment: It looks like you've changed the cron event name and the function.  Can you post your code so I can review for you?

Comment: I simply added the "hol_" prefix to cron event name and the function - following your advice. Code is too long for these comments, but here is a screenshot:  https://i.imgur.com/10mpfHQ.png

Comment: If anyone else can help, I could really use this function working...

Comment: rudtek? Anyone else? Nobody seems to be able to help with this script, here or on other similar questions on the site. Isn't that a relatively basic need? I thought so, but maybe it's more complicated than I thought

Comment: It's not that it's hard.  I have run it myself.  Can you post your code that you used to create the CPT?

Comment: rudtek: For sure, here it is: https://pastebin.com/Gvy9C058 -- I created it using the Metabox plugin UI, FYI.

Comment: Okay, last one.  What are you using to make the custom field?  I think I made an assumption and want to be sure to test exactly what you did.

Comment: Try the code change I added above.  If that doesn't work, still let me know what you are using to make the custom field.

Comment: I used Meta Box (metabox.io) to create both the CPT and the custom field(s). Let me try your updated code...

Comment: rudtek: Unfortunately none of it worked... I tried all the combinations of variants you gave me, switching date format between Y-m-d and Ymd, with either the new code line or the old code line starting with `$expiredate = `. I tried pasting the exact script without adding my prefix. I manually ran the cron after each variant, unfortunately all my events still show "published"

Comment: I just went through and tested the functions. It's definitely working.  Try with my last line now revised once more. If it's not working for you, then there's some troubleshooting we may need to try.

Comment: It's working!! Wowww thank you this has been a thorn in my side for weeks, I'm very thankful!  Now I just need to modify the script so that the post expires at the event_end_date + 1 day instead of the same day, but I will create a new thread for that. Thanks again!

Comment: YEA!  Based on your `<` sign it SHOULD happen only if the date is Greater than today (which should be tomorrow).  ie 20221223 is today.  Your CRON won't draft posts that match todays date.  It will Draft them tomorrrow when the CRON runs.  However if you want to use tomorrow it would just be `$tomorrow = date('YMD',strtotime("+1 days"));`

Comment: Ha, that makes sense, since it's `<` it's actually exactly what I need, so I don't need to change anything. Many many thanks rudek and happy holidays